# Connecting to one proxy after connection to another proxy

Tags: networking, proxy

I am required to connect to a proxy (eg. `proxy.require.com`) before I can access the Internet. After I successfully connect to the Internet, I would like to connect to another proxy server (eg. `proxy.different.com`). How can I achieve this?

> **“My computer -> `proxy.required.com` -> Internet -> `proxy.different.com` -> No more Block sites”**

Comment: what browser/app?

Comment: @FrankThomas do you know of a chrome or FF specific way to chain proxies?  Apparently IE used to have a way though it was removed many many years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe proxifier(for windows) and proxychains(for linux) can do it.

I think i've seen it done in proxifier, there's a dialog box to add proxies, and then when you launch a program it is proxified.

And for proxifier, I think you add proxies to the config file and then have to run the command proxifier then the path of the process.

You may ask "hang on a minute, is that going proxy->proxy->internet   or as you want  proxy->internet->proxy"  <-- Well..  since the proxies you are adding would be across the internet from each other, it'd have to be going proxy->internet->proxy which is as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't trivially do this unless you control proxy.require.com.

You could achieve the same result by using a VPN across the proxy.  I've not used it, but [vpnproxy](http://www.vpnproxy.com/) claims to do just that.  It also looks like [OpenVPN can do it](http://mediarealm.com.au/articles/2014/03/openvpn-client-through-a-restrictive-firewall-and-proxy/).